# Why does one of these very similar jsonpaths work, but not the other?

Tags: postgresql, jsonb, jsonpath

Bumped into this while debugging a query from the ORM and have no idea why it happens. Asking mostly out of curiosity. In PostgreSQL 12.5 the following occurs:

```sql
-- All good:
select ('$[*] ? (@.live_at <= 2020-11-18)')::jsonpath

jsonpath                               |
---------------------------------------|
$[*]?(@."live_at" <= (2020 - 11) - 18) |

-- But then:
select ('$[*] ? (@.live_at <= 2020-05-18)')::jsonpath

SQL Error [42601]: ERROR: syntax error, unexpected IDENT_P at end of jsonpath input
  Position: 9
  SQL Error [42601]: ERROR: syntax error, unexpected IDENT_P at end of jsonpath input
  Position: 9
    SQL Error [42601]: ERROR: syntax error, unexpected IDENT_P at end of jsonpath input
  Position: 9
      SQL Error [42601]: ERROR: syntax error, unexpected IDENT_P at end of jsonpath input
  Position: 9
        ERROR: syntax error, unexpected IDENT_P at end of jsonpath input
  Position: 9
        ERROR: syntax error, unexpected IDENT_P at end of jsonpath input
  Position: 9
```

I've a suspicion that this is related to octal representation, but node seems to eat `2020-05-18` just fine. What gives?

Comment: Not definitive but [JSON numbers](https://www.json.org/img/number.png) can only have a leading zero if that zero is followed by a decimal point (or an `E` and exponent) so `select '05'::json` is an error but `select '5'::json` isn't. Presumably JSONPath uses JSON's formats for numbers so `2020-05-18` isn't a valid expression because `05` is not a valid number. You probably want `'$[*] ? (@.live_at <= "2020-11-18")'::jsonpath` anyway.

Comment: @muistooshort interesting! This is likely the answer as from what I've read around the PostgreSQL team made an effort to stick to the standard. You're right that I did want the quotes there, had to struggle a bit with an ORM to debug this one.

Comment: There doesn't seem to be a good specification for JSONPath, just a very preliminary [draft](https://tools.ietf.org/html/draft-goessner-dispatch-jsonpath-00) and a couple official-ish implementations (JavaScript and PHP). The PostgreSQL people are stuck with making reasonable assumptions about the details I guess.